# Spring properties Java version

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, maven, properties

Изучаю Spring по туториалу и создал Maven проект и теперь в pom.xml лектор написал:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Вопросы:
1. Это минимальные требования проекта? (То есть если я закину допустим на git и человек стянет с Jav(ой) 1.7 либо 7 версией у него будут конфликты или проблемы с приложением?
2. Как будет работает если у меня стоит Jdk 11, а здесь в проперти я указываю 1.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто переменная. Сама по себе она ничего не делает. Вопрос, где её используют.

Скорее всего, её используют в свойствах в Maven Comiple Plugin, как нибудь так:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

Если предположить, что это так, то:

1. Код, написаный и скомпилированый для восьмерки не будет работать на семерке.
2. Проблем не будет.jdk 11 умеет без проблем и поддерживать сорцы для 8 (первый property) и генерировать байткод для 8 (второй property).

Answer (score 1):

1. Скорее всего будет ошибка запуска, т.к. версия приложения несовместима с версией компилятора.
   А вообще [используют](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) `source` и `target`
2. Так же, как и если бы вы запускали на версии 1.8

Comment: 2 Вопрос, а если я там укажу 1.8, а у самого будет стоять 1.7 (7 версия) Java? У меня не будет работать получается?

Comment: Будет ошибка скорее всего